# How to get the Files that have changed since the last run of a Gradle Task?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have the following gradle task:

```
class MyTranslateTask extends DefaultTask {

    @InputFiles FileCollection srcFiles
    @OutputDirectory File destDir

    @TaskAction
    def run() {
    ...
    }
}
```

How can I get all the files from my `srcFiles` which have changed since the last run of this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle 1.6 introduced an incubating feature called `IncrementalTasksInputs` that allows you access to files that were changed or removed since last task run.

ref: https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs.html

```
class IncrementalReverseTask extends DefaultTask {
     @InputDirectory
     def File inputDir

     @OutputDirectory
     def File outputDir

     @TaskAction
     void execute(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
         inputs.outOfDate { change ->
             def targetFile = project.file("$outputDir/${change.file.name}")
             targetFile.text = change.file.text.reverse()
         }

         inputs.removed { change ->
             def targetFile = project.file("$outputDir/${change.file.name}")
             if (targetFile.exists()) {
                 targetFile.delete()
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I have a FileCollection srcFiles as source. How will I get the changed files in this case?

Comment: what happens if you use `@InputFiles` instead of `@InputDirectory` ?